# eclipse maven ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a simple eclipse maven project with the following class:

```
package org.cru.dependencies;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
public class Dependencies {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
    }
}
```

and the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>dependencies</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependencies</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.54</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I can right-click on the JSch in new JSch() and select Open Declared and the source for JSch opens properly. However, when I run the main class I get 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSch

Even if I create a lib folder and place the jsch jar in the lib folder and add the jar to the build path I get the same error. Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: create your project with `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, then open your project using the generated project file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem:

rm -rf ~/.m2/repository
then, define the project again in eclipse